# Runas CMD is not working because of quoting

Tags: batch-file, cmd, runas

I'm using this line in a batch file:

```
Runas /user:domain\user "cmd /C echo Test > C:\Program Files\Install2AgentService\Install2AgentWinService.exe.config"
```

The problem ist, this is only working if the path of the file has no blank spaces. And I can not put the path in quotation marks as usually because the whole CMD-command has to be in quotation marks.

```
Runas /user:domain\user "cmd /C echo Test > "C:\Program Files\Install2AgentService\Install2AgentWinService.exe.config""
```

Even escaping the double quotation marks is not working.

```
Runas /user:domain\user "cmd /C echo Test > ""C:\Program Files\Install2AgentService\Install2AgentWinService.exe.config"""
```

Does anybody have an idea how to deal with that problem? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this workaround would do the trick for you if you always expect this to be in ProgramFiles. `Runas /user:domain\user "cmd /C echo Test > %ProgramFiles%\Install2AgentService\Install2AgentWinService.exe.config"`. Also, you aren't showing us just how you are escaping this string.

Comment: Ah sorry, no there are more spaces than the program files one... I added the other two ways I already tried

Comment: Use short 8.3 names to get rid of spaces in path:
`Runas /user:domain\user "cmd /C echo Test > C:\PROGRA~1\Install2AgentService\Install2AgentWinService.exe.config"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape inner double quotes using `\` *Reverse Solidus* (backslash) as follows:

```
Runas /user:domain\user "cmd /C echo Test>\"C:\Program Files\Install2AgentService\Install2AgentWinService.exe.config\""
```

**Resources** (equivalent):

- `runas /?` from an open command prompt
- [RUNAS at *ss64.com*](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)

*Example use case*:

```
d:\bat> runas /noprofile /user:user "cmd /V:ON /C whoami&echo \"!CD!\"&echo !CD! Test runas>>\"%CD%\test runas.txt\"&pause"
Enter the password for user:
Attempting to start cmd /V:ON /C whoami&echo "!CD!"&echo !CD! Test runas>>"d:\bat\test runas.txt"&pause as user "MY-PC\user" ...

d:\bat> type "test runas.txt"
C:\WINDOWS\system32 Test runas
C:\WINDOWS\system32 Test runas
```

Comment: I thought I tried that before, but it's working. Thanks a lot!